# css? centered text with border either side

Tags: html, css, border

as seen here:
http://mathieuwhite.com/

it says "Work" in the middle wit hwhat seems to be a border either side or is this an image?
can anyone give me a code example? thank you

Comment: You just linked to a code example. Dig through the HTML and CSS with your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

It is a border hack made with CSS ::before and ::after.
Here is his code.

```
body #container section h2::before, body #container section h2::after {
position: absolute;
top: 7px;
height: 1px;
background-color: transparent;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
content: "";
```

And please take care of your typos...

Comment: I want to do similar with this:

Comment: .title h3  { font-size:22px; line-height:22px; color:#375d81; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ffffff; text-align:center; margin-top:20px; padding-top:0; width:auto; }

Comment: but have not managed to do so even with your snippet, could you help please? Ann.

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of your HTML structure?

Comment: <div class="title">
             <h3>Photos</h3>
             <br class="clear" />
            </div>

Comment: Then modify the snippet with title h3::before,title h3::after{...}

Comment: ok i have now managed to get lines but they go through the text - how do i get a gap around the text ??

Comment: The guy made a hack using a central div and a background centered. For more informations, juste use "Inspect Element" function in Chrome or the Firebug plugin for Firefox. You'll learn more from this. Vote my answer up or accept it to close the topic then.